# AndroidAnnotations with Spring Rest Template does not work when obfuscated

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

My Android application uses AndroidAnnotations and Spring Rest Template. When creating a *debug build*, it runs fine. When I create a *release build* however, the REST call does not work. Below are some relevant snippets from my code and build configuration.

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Bean
    protected MyService myService;

    @Background
    protected void fetchData() {
        try {
            data = myService.getData();
        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), dae.getMessage(), dae);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@EBean
public class MyService {
    @RestService
    protected MyRestClient myRestClient;

    public Data getData() {
        return myRestClient.getData();
    }
}
```

**RestClient**

```
@Rest(converters = { GsonHttpMessageConverter.class },
      interceptors = { AuthenticationInterceptor.class, UserAgentInterceptor.class },
      rootUrl = "https://myhost/rest")
public interface MyShiftRestClient {
    @Get("/data")
    Data getData();
}
```

**ProGuard configuration**

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.springframework.**

-keep class com.mypackage.** {
  public protected private *;
}

-keepclassmembers public class org.springframework.** {
   public *;
}
```

When running the obfuscated app, the Data object that is returned by `MyRestClient` is an empty object, i.e. it is initialised but none of its instance variables have any values. I guess it has to do with my ProGuard configuration, that's why I added the last configuration statement, but it had no effect. There is no Exception being logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to keep members of Data class too. Data class properties must be untouched to allow Gson converter fill it, as it is done based on property names.

Good luck.

Comment: The `Data` class is in a `com.mypackage.model` package, and thus excluded from ProGuard. I checked with dex2jar and JAD and the class is untouched.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem but try to exclude the Gson packages (com.google.gson) too from ProGuard.

Comment: Well, that more-or-less did the trick, after excluding `sun.misc.Unsafe` as well. See the [example ProGuard config for GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) for reference.